# Opencart: wrong pagination route

Tags: php, opencart

When I'm at the products list and try to move to another page by using my pagination buttons, it fires a 404 Not Found Error. This is due to wrong routing, which I can't resolve. The current paginations is:

localhost/my_store/index.php?route=product/category&page=1

If I manually change it to:

localhost/my_store/index.php?route=product/all&page=1

It works fine. I checked my pagination script but I don't know what are the arguments to pass to my URL:

```
for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
    if ($page == $i) {
        $output .= '<li class="active"><span>' . $i . '</span></li>';
    } else {
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Full snippet: http://pastebin.com/3fSECkPG

How can I fix my pagination routing?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it by changing my pagination route at my Products Controller (found at catalog/controller/product/all.php). Search for your Pagination routing variable and change it to match your products page list (mine was all.php as mentioned):

catalog/controller/product/all.php

```
$pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/all', 'page={page}');
```

If anyone knows a better and proper way to fix this issue, I appreciate very much.